# Soft brick after dunking phone in coffee

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, unbricking, water-damage

I (accidentally) dunked my Samsung Galaxy S S7562 in coffee. When I found it, it was swimming around in the coffee in my bag. It seemed to be working when I shut it down and took out the battery.

I left it in uncooked rice overnight. Then, I dried it under the sun for a few hours before putting the battery back. I can only get to the Samsung splash screen and (for a few seconds) to the custom ROM installation screen. Is this a characteristic soft brick?

I suspect there might be hardware damage because of coffee particles. What can I do at this stage?

Answer (score 2):

My brother's S3 Mini had a nice water trip on Espain beach. It turned on, but it had software issues such as apps opening randomly, volume changing itself, and random reboots. When the battery went empty, it didn't turn on.

My brother tried his friend's S3 Mini battery, and it worked fine, but all the problems remained. So, he bought a new one.

Try another battery. If still doesn't boot, take it to the service center. Last thing is to buy a new phone.